# Elm - StartApp type issue

Tags: elm

I have a `Main` module that imports a `Users` module (without exposing anything).

In `Main` I'm using startApp the normal way, using only definitions from the `Main` module:

```
app =
  StartApp.start
    { init = init
    , inputs = [Signal.map TopBar topBarActionPort]
    , update = update
    , view = view
    }
```

But Elm Reactor is complaining and is trying to use the `Users` module which doesn't make sense. See message below.

Function `start` is expecting the argument to be:

```
{ ...
, inputs : List (Signal Users.Action)
, update : Users.Action -> Model -> ( Model, Effects Users.Action )
, view : Address Users.Action -> Model -> Html
}
```

But it is:

```
{ ...
, inputs : List (Signal Action)
, update : Action -> Model -> ( Model, Effects Action )
, view : Address Action -> Model -> Html
}
```

How to make the compiler use the `Main` module functions as it should be??

Comment: This is usually indicative of a type inference error that "bubbles up" to `start`. Try adding type annotations onto all functions exposed in the `Users` module (`Main` too) and I have a hunch you'll find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks @ChadGilbert, problem solved by mapping `Users` effects into `Main` effects. My modules architecture is finally stable.

Comment: @ChadGilbert please, write an answer, so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually indicative of a type inference error that "bubbles up" to `start`.

Type annotations are not required in Elm, and if you don't explicitly give the function a type signature, Elm will infer it.

For a trivial example - suppose I had these two functions:

```elm
getUsers = { name = "Bob", age = 42 }

getUserNames = List.map .name getUsers -- compiler error!
```

The name of `getUsers` seems to imply that it should return a list, but based on its return type, Elm compiles `getUsers` as type `User` instead of `List User`. Therefore, `getUsers` compiles just fine (albeit with an inferred type signature that *you* don't expect).

However, the compiler is going to tell you there is something wrong with the function `getUserNames` even though the problem originates in the fact that `getUsers` is incorrectly defined.

This bubbling up effect is probably why you're seeing weird compiler errors pointing at the `start` function. The way to track down which functions are incorrect is to add type annotations in all your modules.

Consider the trivial example above. If I were to annotate my functions, the compiler would then complain about the function at the root of the problem.

```elm
getUsers : List User
getUsers = { name = "Bob", age = 42 } -- compiler error!

getUserNames : List String
getUserNames = List.map .name getUsers
```

Elm's type inference is powerful and very useful, but it can sometimes cause odd and seemingly unrelated compiler errors if used in a deeply nested fashion. A good rule of thumb that has served me well is to annotate all publicly exposed functions in my modules.